# Can a subspace be its own additive identity?

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem is for Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition:

Problem 18/Chapter 1:

**Does the operation of addition on the subspaces of V have an additive identity? Which subspaces have additive inverses?**

My doubt is in my attempt of answer for the first question:

Clearly for a Subspace $U$ of a vector space $V$ we have that the sum with the subspace $\{0\}$ implies:
$$U+\{0\}=U$$ (which is the answer given in previous posts)
However, problem 15 in the same chapter gives the result that $U+U=U$

We know that the additive identity is unique, then, ***Do the later results imply a contradiction?***  Since the addition of $U$ or $\{0\}$ gave the same result(both act as additive identity) for $U$.

I would appreciate if someone can illuminate this basic question

Comment: If something is an additive identity, it is meant to be that for *all* $U$'s, and not change when you switch from one $U$ to another. In your example, $U$ (as an "alternative additive identity" for $U$) - *depends* on $U$.

Comment: Now i understand, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection of all subspaces of $V$ is a set.  The author, Axler,has defined an operation for combining two such subspaces, namely $+$.

Remember:

- The **additive identity** is "the thing that *always* leaves the original thing unchanged."  In this case $\{0\}+U=U$.  Since $U$ *does not* leave the original thing (namely $\{0\}$) unchanged, $U$ cannot be the additive identity.
- An element's **additive inverse** is "the thing that gets the given element back to the additive identity." So *if  $U$ has an additive inverse* $\overline U$, then $\overline U$ is "the thing that gets $U$ back to the additive identity. (See previous bullet.)

So, **"No, the facts you have noticed above are *not a contradiction*."**  In fact, what you *have* noticed is that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then both the equations you wrote above are in fact true, i.e. $U+\{0\}=U$ and $U=U+U$.  So, **if $U$ has an additive inverse**, $\overline U$, the fact that $\{0\}+U=U+U$ means that by adding $\overline U$ to both sides we get $\{0\}+(U+\overline U) =U+(U+ \overline U)$. This simplifies to tell us $\{0\}=U$. (Reason: Adding the additive identity to both sides of an equation must leave the original term on each side unchanged.)

Comment: All these three solution are awesome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

If $U\ne \{0\}$ then it's not an additive identity. It would have to satisfy $W + U = W$ **for all subspaces** $W$, not only for the case $W=U$.

There's no such thing as "identity for U".

Comment: This is more than clear! I really appreciate. Thank you for taking the time

Answer (score -1):

It's a feature of *groups* that if $a+b=a$ for *some* $a$, then $a+b=a$ for *all* $a$, making $b$ the additive identity. Subspaces with subspace addition don't form a group, though, just a monoid. And in monoids, an element $b$ satisfying $a+b=a$ for one single $a$ is not necessarily an additive identity.

For instance, in the monoid $(\mathbb Z,\cdot)$ we have $0\cdot0=0$, but $0$ is not the neutral element since, for instance, $0\cdot1\neq1$. Your case is just another example of this behavior.